# DAX: Reset a cumulative total by certain date thresholds

Tags: powerbi, dax

I have a cumulative total of CE's `CE's cumulative` (see below).

I need the cumulative total to reset to 0 after hitting the `ResetDate`

Looked all around forums but unable to find the answer, hope you can help me out.

```
CE's cumulative =
CALCULATE(
   SUM (CE's),
     FILTER( ALL( DimDate),
     DimDate[Date] <= MAX( DimDate[Date] )
           )
         )
```

```
Date    CE's cumulative ResetDate
10-10-2019  77.670.099  
11-10-2019  78.057.691  11-10-2019
12-10-2019  78.114.554  
13-10-2019  78.234.181  
14-10-2019  78.469.789  
15-10-2019  78.709.015  15-10-2019
16-10-2019  80.070.020
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this below measure-

```
cumulative_sum = 

VAR current_date = MIN(your_table_name[Date])

VAR last_reset_date = 
CALCULATE(
    MAX(your_table_name[ResetDate]),
    FILTER(
        ALL(your_table_name),
        your_table_name[Date] <= current_date
    )
)

RETURN 
IF(
    last_reset_date = BLANK(), 
    CALCULATE(
        SUM(your_table_name[CE's cumulative]),
        FILTER(
            ALL(your_table_name),
            your_table_name[Date] <= current_date
        )
    ),
    CALCULATE(
        SUM(your_table_name[CE's cumulative]),
        FILTER(
            ALL(your_table_name),
            your_table_name[Date] <= current_date
            && your_table_name[Date] >= last_reset_date
        )
    )
)
```

Here is the output-

[image]

Comment: Nice to see it helped :)

Answer (score 0):

I would find the closest ResetDate to my Date and then use that in the filter:

```
VAR currentDate = SELECTEDVALUE(dimDate[date])
VAR lastResetDate = LASTDATE(FILTER(ALL(dimDate[ResetDate], dimDate[ResetDate] < currentDate)))

RETURN CALCULATE(SUM(CE's), 
                ALL(dimDate), 
                dimDate[date] > lastResetDate && dimDate[date] <= currentDate)
```